# Having grid items display based on their size MUI Quilted Grid Layout

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Image of Issue

[image: Image of Issue]

Apologies for the zoomed out image, but I am using MUI in React to display a bunch of nested cards dynamically (The data has nested components rendering other components).

- Each grid has cards that has grids within them and cards within the grids. I am trying to have the cards fit the page.
- So in the image below, I would like the grid component on the second row and second column to come up to where the grid component on the first row second column ends.

I've been searching around trying to find the answer this question but a newbie to frontend so I am not sure how to phrase it. Any advice would be helpful!

Edit:
I am curious about making a quilted grid layout

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles({
    gridContainer: {
      paddingLeft: "85px",
      paddingRight: "85px",
    },
    root: {
      minWidth: 200,
    },
    bullet: {
      display: "inline-block",
      margin: "0 2px",
      transform: "scale(0.8)",
    },
    title: {
      fontSize: 14,
    },
    pos: {
      marginBottom: 12,
    },
    parentFlexRight: {
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "flex-end",
    },
    leftAlignItem: {
      marginRight: "auto",
      marginTop: "auto",
    },
    stretch: { height: "100%" },
    item: {
      display: "flex",
      flexDirection: "column",
    },
  });

  var checkIndex = 0;
  const renderCourseRequirements = (RequiredCourses) => {
    return (
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={0}
        direction="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="center"
      >
        {RequiredCourses.map((course, index) => {
          var Index = checkIndex;
          checkIndex = checkIndex + 1;
          return (
            <Grid key={index} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
              <Card sx={{ width: 200 }} variant="outlined">
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
                    {course}
                  </Typography>
                  <Checkbox
                    id={`custom-checkbox-${Index}`}
                    name={course}
                    value={course}
                    checked={checkedState.includes(course)}
                    onChange={() => handleOnChange(course)}
                  />
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    );
  };
  const renderComponents = (components) => {
    return (
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={0}
        direction="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="center"
      >
        {components.map((component, index) => {
          return (
            <Grid
              container
              spacing={0}
              direction="column"
              alignItems="stretch"
              justifyContent="center"
              key={index}
              item
              xs={12}
              sm={6}
              md={4}
            >
              <Card className={classes.root} variant="outlined">
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography
                    className={classes.title}
                    color="textSecondary"
                    gutterBottom
                  >
                    {component.component_name}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                    Required Number of Courses: {component.required_num_courses}
                  </Typography>
                  {renderCourseRequirements(component.course_list)}
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            </Grid>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    );
  };

  const renderComponentFamilies = (componentFamilies) => {
    return (
      <Grid container spacing={4} className={classes.item}>
        {componentFamilies.map((componentFamily, index) => {
          if (componentFamily.component_list.length > 1)
            return (
              <Grid key={index} xs={8} sm={6} md={4}>
                <Card className={classes.stretch} variant="outlined">
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography
                      className={classes.title}
                      color="textSecondary"
                      gutterBottom
                    >
                      {componentFamily.component_family_name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                      Required Number of Components :{" "}
                      {componentFamily.required_num_components}
                    </Typography>
                    {renderComponents(componentFamily.component_list)}
                  </CardContent>
                </Card>
              </Grid>
            );
          return (
            <>
              <Grid key={index} item xs={12} sm={6} md={4}>
                {renderComponents(componentFamily.component_list)}
              </Grid>
            </>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of resources that may point you in the right direction. Setting some CSS breakpoints may also work with your content.

https://mui.com/system/sizing/
https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/?expand-path=$.breakpoints.values

If that's not what you're looking for, I'd recommend wrapping your elements in an element that references a method with a 'resize' event listener that makes your preferred changes after the resize is triggered.

Comment: There's no way to set the CSS so that the elements just auto-size?

Comment: I'd look into CSS's resize/overflow property or something like max-width. Percentage values are a good way to keep track of size as the window increase. You may be able to set something up in the parent body as well.